# password_change function in Django User Authenication

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to allow the user to change the password and I am using the django-in-built password_change function. I would like to use the default template-name and password_change_form but I want to change the post_change_redirect argument to specific to my website.

How do I change that only while keeping the rest the same?

From Django Documentation:

```
password_change(request[, template_name, post_change_redirect, password_change_form])
Allows a user to change their password.

URL name: password_change

Optional arguments:

template_name: The full name of a template to use for displaying the password change form. Defaults to registration/password_change_form.html if not supplied.
post_change_redirect: The URL to redirect to after a successful password change.
password_change_form: A custom "change password" form which must accept a user keyword argument. The form is responsible for actually changing the user's password. Defaults to PasswordChangeForm.
Template context:
```

form: The password change form (see password_change_form above).

Need some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: `password_change(request, post_change_redirect='my_url')` ?

Comment: def lmlogout(request):
    """
    logout view
    """    
    return password_change(request, post_change_redirect='my_url') Correct Usage?

Comment: It's best to just try it in Django, but that's how I'll use that function.

Comment: @WojciechŻółtak add yours as an answer...

Comment: btw did you import this from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change?

Comment: That's what documentation says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to define a view, which will be serving a modified `password_change` view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change

def change_password(request):
    return password_change(request, post_change_redirect='%my_post_change_url%')
```

And that's all.

You must only remember that, it'll redirect you to the default login-page if you're not logged-in and that you have to write a password change page template (named `registration/password_change_form.html` by default)